# Creating a dummy container so the inner object can be re-assigned and not be lost? (C#)

Tags: c#, reference

I have an object that is used extensively in one of my classes. However, I have another class that stores a reference to that object and later may need to re-assign it.

As we all know, if a class contains a reference to an object stored as a member variable and then re-assigns it, then the reference is lost and now there are two objects.

One could argue the use of the ref keyword but unfortunately I cannot as I store the member variable in the objects constructor and then later re-assign it in one of the class's methods.

A solution to this problem would be to just create a small dummy container class and pass that around instead and then share this dummy container between the two classes. Both classes can then feel free to re-assign the inner member variable and it will never be lost or copied.

Now you may be wondering, "it seems like you already have your answer! What is your question?" Well, I don't have an exact question. I'm just wondering if this kind of thing is done. Is it an anti-pattern? Is there a better way? A refactoring?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ComponentModel architecture. There you have the [IServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.aspx) interface, which has the GetService method to get a instance of the registered service. There is also the [IServiceContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.iservicecontainer.aspx) interface which has additional methods for unregistering existing services and registering new services, that can be then used in the outer scope. There is already an implementation in the framework, the [ServiceContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.servicecontainer.aspx) class, that can be used.

```
class A
{
    private readonly IServiceContainer _services;
    public A(IServiceContainer services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public void Call() 
    {
         var service = (ISomeService)_services.GetService(typeof(ISomeService));
         service.DoSomething();
    }

    public void ChangeService()
    {
         // set the new service instance as 
         // the ISomeService in the service container
         var newService = new SomeService();
         _services.RemoveService(typeof(ISomeService), true);
         _services.AddService(typeof(ISomeService), newService);             
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var svc = new ServiceContainer();
var a1 = new A(svc);
var a2 = new A(svc);
a1.ChangeService();
a1.Call(); // call the created service
a2.Call(); // the service created in a1 will be called
a2.ChangeService();
a1.Call(); // the service created in a2 will be called
```

Comment: Might be overkill considering there is this only one object though, right?

Comment: Well, this would be the most OO way of doing it. And it is allready implemented in the framework, so you don't need to create your own infrastructure for it.